# copy final output of Console.Writeline() statements to a text file and array c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, io-redirection, console.writeline

I'm using VS2013 and I'm new to programming. In my program I have Console.Writeline statements like below. Frequency is a double variable that outputs a peak values of frequencies in real-time.

```
 if (Frequency > 328 && Frequency < 330)
 {                               
     Console.WriteLine(Frequency.ToString());
 }
 if (Frequency > 245 && Frequency < 247)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(Frequency.ToString());
 }
 if (Frequency > 195 && Frequency < 197)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(Frequency.ToString());
 }
```

Once I run the program, it outputs like this.

```
196.5654296875
246.9658203125
196.3984375
246.0322265625
196.5654296875
246.798828125
246.46484375
329.0322265625
329.0322265625
329.265625
```

I want to copy above whole final output numbers to a text file and to array also. But I don't have any idea how to do this. Please help me.

Comment: Do you want some code to write out to a text file in your code? Glad to give some

Comment: _System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\\dir1\\file1.txt",ToString())_. To store text in an array, rather use _List<int> frequencies = new List<int>()_ and store freqs : _frequencies.Add(Frequency)_

Comment: thaks for replying me  Graffito and Drew . graffito that's exactly what i wanted and thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

You can store it to a `List<string>` and have the same printed to a file like

```
 List<string> freq = new List<string>();

 if (Frequency > 328 && Frequency < 330)
 {                               
     Console.WriteLine(Frequency.ToString());
     freq.Add(Frequency.ToString());
 }

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\test\frequency_output.txt", freq.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the simplest way to do it, would be instantiate a writer that can write to file, and then call it's `WriteLine()` method similarlilly to console one, as such:

```
using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("C:\numbers.txt"))
{
    if (Frequency > 328 && Frequency < 330)
    {                               
     Console.WriteLine(Frequency.ToString());
     outfile.WriteLine(Frequency.ToString());
    }
    if (Frequency > 245 && Frequency < 247)
    {
     Console.WriteLine(Frequency.ToString());
     outfile.WriteLine(Frequency.ToString());
    }
    if (Frequency > 195 && Frequency < 197)
    {
     Console.WriteLine(Frequency.ToString());
     outfile.WriteLine(Frequency.ToString());
    }   
}
```

You can find more on StreamWriter here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/System.IO.StreamWriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This is not very effective of course, however it should you get started.

There is whole lot of material on working with files in C#, so you should not have problems with finding help there as well.